# Proto2 encode/decode issues after adding new message

Tags: protocol-buffers, version, grpc, decode, encode

I'm fairly new to protocol buffers but have been trying to learn them as a means of sending data via MQTT. So far, I've been fine with creating proto messages and compiling them for python runtime, until I started to notice incompatibility between versions of my protobufs.

When I add a message type (no changes to existing messages/fields) to my server-side proto definitions without updating my client side proto definitions, decoding messages sent to the server give me non-deterministic results.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

**Client proto:**

```json
message Wrapper {
    optional uint32 id = 1;
    optional string name = 2;
    oneof payload {
        Event event = 3;
        Command command = 4;
    }
}

message Event {
    uint32 event_id = 1;
    oneof event_payload {
        LoginEvent login_event = 2;
        LogoffEvent logoff_event = 3;
    }
}
```

**Server Proto:**

```json
message Wrapper {
    optional uint32 id = 1;
    optional string name = 2;
    oneof payload {
        Event event = 3;
        Command command = 4;
    }

message Event {
    uint32 event_id = 1;
    oneof event_payload {
        LoginEvent login_event = 2;
        LogoffEvent logoff_event = 3;
        NewUserEvent new_user_event = 4;
    }
}
```

I will encode and send a message from the client:

```json
message Wrapper {
    id = 12345;
    name = John;
    event = {
        login_event = ...
    }
}
```

And will decode the message on the server and get:

```json
message Wrapper {
    id = 12345;
    name = John;
    event = {
        logoff_event = ...
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: The decoded message type isn't deterministic and changes between messages

Can someone explain why adding an event type seems to screw up decode? Or any best-practices I should obey to improve version compatibility? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This *may* be a side-effect of the Python implementation rather than a bug.

You don't include the code you're using to (un)marshal the protobufs.

In your example, does `logoff_event` contain a `LogoffEvent` message type?

You say non-deterministic? Do you see different `event_payload` messages types on the server for the same message sent by the client?

What is returned by:

```py
msg = Wrapper() # Your decoded message
assert msg.event.WhichOneof("event_payload")
# or
assert msg.event.HasField("login_event")
```

See [Python Generated Code: OneOf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#oneof)

##### Update 210927

I'm unable to repro the behavior you observe; it works as expected for me.

Client:

```
import client_pb2

msg = client_pb2.Wrapper()

msg.id=0
msg.name="Test"
msg.event.event_id=1
msg.event.login_event.y="Hello Freddie"

print(msg)

f=open("message","wb")
f.write(msg.SerializeToString())
f.close()
```

Yields:

```
id: 0
name: "Test"
event {
  event_id: 1
  login_event {
    y: "Hello Freddie"
  }
}
```

Server:

```
import server_pb2

msg = server_pb2.Wrapper()

f=open("message","rb")
msg.ParseFromString(f.read())
f.close

assert msg.event.WhichOneof("event_payload")
assert msg.event.HasField("login_event")

print(msg)
```

Yields:

```
id: 0
name: "Test"
event {
  event_id: 1
  login_event {
    y: "Hello Freddie"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah the `logff_event` does contain a LogoffEvent message type, and yeah that's exactly what I meant by non-deterministic. I may be incorrect about that though, there may be a mapping/pattern I'm just missing. Also, to unmarshal I use the FromString method and then convert the msg to a json using json_format.MessageToJson which I end up loading as a python dictionary.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It works as intended for me.